# How to make .webm seekable in JS

Tags: javascript, webm

I am trying to create a program that records a chrome tab and save it using `puppeteer` and `puppeteer-tab-recorder`. The problem is that it saves the recording as `.webm` which is the only supported version for now. I need to make the `.webm` seekable so I searched and found `ts-ebml` library. I tried to use it but no luck as this package is published 6 years ago and I can't find good documentation on how to use it to make `.webm` seekable. I tried reading their documentation and it says clearly that it is capable of this task but with no examples. can someone help me ?

what I tried:

```
function segmentWebM(inputPath, outputPath) {
  const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(inputPath); // Load the WebM file
  const decoder = new ebml.Decoder();
  decoder.write(fileBuffer);
  decoder.end();
  const tree = ebml.tools.makeMetadataSeekable(decoder.metadatas);
  const seekableWebMBuffer = Buffer.from(
    ebml.tools.makeMetadataSeekable(tree, true)
  );
  fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, seekableWebMBuffer);
}
```

It says it can't find the function `.write` in the `decoder`. only decode function is available and the other are just set to private.

Comment: You could take your chunks, and merge them sequentially in a .MP4. Or you could export multiple videos, and merge them at the end of the task, using FFMPEG or similar.

Comment: can you give an example using the library I mentioned "puppeteer-tab-recorder" @NVRM

Comment: You have to import another library, dedicated to video manipulation and encoding. Since you are running node.js, it will be very easy...